# function add() numbers with prompt

Tags: javascript, function, addition, prompt

I want to simple add number code using prompt

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = prompt("");
  var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += x;}
  })();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is more complicated than it need be. There is no need for a nested function to do the math. You must also convert the user-supplied data to a number (this can be done by prepending a `+` to the data).

Also, your code does not follow best-practices and standards.

See the comments in the code below.

```js
// Get references to the HTML elements you'll use in JavaScript
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var counter = 0; // Running total will be here

// Set up event handling in JavaScript, not HTML
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter += +prompt("What is the number to add?"); // Convert response to number and add to counter
  output.textContent = counter; // Place result back into the document (use .textContent, not .innerHTML)
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">+</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I defined the function from an IIFE so `counter` doesn't pollute global scope - then, just return the function, no need for anything more complicated

```js
const myFunction = (() => {
  let counter = 0;
  return () => {
    counter += Number(prompt('Number?'));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter;
  };
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Avoiding global scope pollution is very worthy. Unfortunately, this creates a global variable named `myFunction`. To fix that, register the handler from JavaScript

Comment: @AluanHaddad Or, just place all of the code in an IIFE.

Comment: @ScottMarcus right. Your answer wrapped in an IIFE is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

- The main problem is the creation of the function `add` in every click event.
- Just put it outside from the function `myFunction`.
- You need to convert to number the entered value, i.e using the operator `+`.

```js
var add = (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function(x) {
    return counter += +x;
  }
})();

function myFunction() {
  var x = prompt("");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(x);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Recommendation:**

Use the function **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to bind the event `click`.

```js
// This is to illustrate the usage of 'addEventListener'.
// The function getElementsByTagName gets the whole set of elements button.
// In your case it doesn't make sense because you have only one.
// Like I said, this is just to illustrate.
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var btn of buttons) btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

//-----------

var add = (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function(x) {
    return counter += +x /*Convert to number*/;
  }
})();

function myFunction() {
  var x = prompt("");
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = add(x);
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: There's only one button. Why use `.getElementsByTagName()` (which not only scans the whole DOM for elements, but is a live node list so it scans again every time the variable is accessed) and then loop though a list that contains just one element?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's just an example!

Comment: Ok, but maybe point out what you are showing so that the OP understands when it might be beneficial?

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry to hound you, but you don't need `.getElementsByTagName()` and `for/of` to demonstrate `.addEventListener()`. A newbie is going to think this is the way to handle setting up a listener for just one element.